# I want to enable and disable radio button group using a check box

Tags: html, angularjs

html code where button groups are declared

```
<tr>
  <div class="checkbox">
  <td class="fc">INACTIVE <label> <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle-checkbox" ng-change="isCheckboxChecked()"  >        </label></td>
  <td style="visibility:$scope.isCheckboxChecked()=="true"">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn-primary btn ">
      <input type="radio" name="options4"   ng-model=" option4"  value="rewards"  ng-required="!option4" > Rewards
      </label>
      <label class="btn-primary btn ">
      <input type="radio" name="options4"   ng-model=" option4"  value="awards" ng-required="!option4"> Awards
      </label>
      <label class="btn-primary btn">
      <input type="radio" name="options4"   ng-model=" option4"  value="offers" ng-required="!option4"> Offers
      </label>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

angular script for that checkbox.

```
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.isCheckboxChecked = function() {
     return ($scope.isCheckboxChecked(true)
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue here ?

Comment: button group doesnot get disabled with this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**HTML**

```
 <tr>
 <div class="checkbox"><td class="fc">INACTIVE <label> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked"  >        </label></td>
<td ng-if="isChecked==true"><div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn-primary btn ">
  <input type="radio" name="options4"   ng-model=" option4"  value="rewards"  ng-required="!option4" > Rewards
   </label>
  <label class="btn-primary btn ">
  <input type="radio" name="options4"   ng-model=" option4"  value="awards" ng-required="!option4"> Awards
   </label>
     <label class="btn-primary btn">
    <input type="radio" name="options4"   ng-model=" option4"  value="offers" ng-required="!option4"> Offers
     </label>
     </div></td>
      </tr>
```

**JS**

```
 No need of any JS. ;)
```

Comment: This won't disable button group instead it will hide it. I hope this what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: is it possible to disable the  button group.

Comment: Yes, use ng-disabled="isChecked==true" on each <input type="radio"> elements if you want to disable radio buttons. I don't know this will work if you use it on div directly.

Comment: i want to disable before it checked what i have to do?

Comment: you mean if checkbox is checked radio buttons should disabled?

Comment: radio buttons  should be enabled if checkbox is checked.

Comment: then use ng-disabled="isChecked==false"

Answer (score 0):

Ng-disabled on fieldset is that what you need.

```
<tr>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <td class="fc">INACTIVE <label><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle-checkbox" ng-model="checked" ></label></td>
        <td>
            <fieldset class="btn-group" ng-disabled="checked">
              <label class="btn-primary btn ">
                <input type="radio" name="options4"   ng-model=" option4"  value="rewards"  ng-required="!option4" > Rewards
              </label>
              <label class="btn-primary btn ">
                <input type="radio" name="options4"   ng-model=" option4"  value="awards" ng-required="!option4"> Awards
              </label>
              <label class="btn-primary btn">
                <input type="radio" name="options4"   ng-model=" option4"  value="offers" ng-required="!option4"> Offers
              </label>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

Comment: Maybe change ng-disabled="checked" to ng-disabled="!checked"?